# how to use libsvim in c#

Tags: c#, libsvm

I download libsvm for C# from http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/
and I find some sample code for it. sample code is:

```
var prob = ProblemHelper.ReadAndScaleProblem(TRAINING_FILE);
            var test = ProblemHelper.ReadAndScaleProblem(TEST_FILE);
            var svm = new C_SVC(prob, KernelHelper.RadialBasisFunctionKernel(gamma), C);
            var accuracy = svm.GetCrossValidationAccuracy(nr_fold);// with nr_fold > 1
            for (int i = 0; i < test.l; i++)
            {
                var x = test.x[i];
                var y = test.y[i];
                var predictedY = svm.Predict(x); // returns the predicted value for 'x' attributes
                var probabilities = svm.PredictProbabilities(x);  // returns the probabilities for each class
                // Note : in about accuracy% of cases, 'predictedY' should be equal to 'y'
            }
```

but libsvm namespace doesn't conatin "ProblemHelper" & "C_SVC". is problem from code?
can anyone help me by a sample code ?
thanks

Comment: You know that is not a .NET library right?

Comment: I don't understand what you say! what should I do?  should I download another file or I should use it in another way?